# How to add a .framework (done in obj-c) inside a swift pod lib

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to include a .framework inside my pod project done in swift.

I have included it in my .podspec using "s.vendored_frameworks" like this:

```
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Core'
  s.version          = '0.1.8'
  s.summary          = 'This is a pod with a MVVM skeleton that helps to start swiftUI projects'



  s.ios.deployment_target = '14.0'
  s.swift_versions = '5.2'

  s.source_files = 'Core/Classes/**/*'
  
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'TGCore' => ['Core/Assets/*']
  }

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Core/Frameworks/ScaleBleManagerSDK.framework'
  s.resources = "Core/Assets/*"


   s.frameworks = 'SwiftUI', 'Foundation'
   s.dependency 'Moya', '<= 15.0.0-alpha.1'

end
```

ScaleBleManagerSDK.framework has been done in objective-c. In my podfile I added

```
use_frameworks!
```

So, when I try to use ScaleBleManagerSDK inside my development pod by creating a function I cannot access any of the headers of the framework I did import in the podspec.

What I need to do to access to the headers?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your headers are put in `target -> build phrases -> headers -> public`

[image: 888]